# Create a __cdecl to __thiscall wrapper function on c++

Tags: c++, closures, libraries, calling-convention, dynamic-loading

I need to dynamically make a function that can be called by an external library using the `__cdecl` calling convention, and that then redirect the call to a method on a class, effectively serving as a proxy to a `__thiscall` calling convention.

The main idea is that this program (`program1`) should receive a function pointer from an external application (`program2`), package it into an object that can query us (`program1`) to know if the call to `program2` should be made or not, then pass it to the library.

I have a vague idea of what a header for such class should look like

```
template <typename F, class C>
class this_call_wrapper
{
public:
    // Creates a wrapper function that calls `operator()` on `object`
    // `operator()` should take the same arguments as `F`
    this_call_wrapper(const C* object);
    // Deallocates memory used by this and the wrapper
    ~this_call_wrapper();
    // Returns the pointer to the function wrapper
    F* get_wrapper();
private:
    C* object;
    F* wrapper;
};
```

Are there any libraries out there that provide similar functionality? If not, how can I implement this in C++?

Comment: does the external library allow you to pass in a `void*` context variable? Because if not, I don't think there is any way to do it without UB.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to talk in __cdecl and __thiscall terms rather than in normal standard C++ terms (member function, non-member function)?

Comment: @Mgetz No it won't, that's the problem. I need to fabricate a function at run-time that  can be called with the ``__cdecl`` calling convention, that then redirects the call to the correct object member. This way, you "detach" the member function from the class, making it possible to call it without needing ``this`` to be set. For each different instance, you'll have a different proxy function.

Comment: @n.m. The library I am using uses the ``__cdecl`` calling convention for that specific call. I'd prefer to be precise just in case.

Comment: @Facundo then you'll have to use a global variable, because there is no safe way to do that.

Comment: @Mgetz a global variable for what?

Comment: Your problem boils down to creation of trampolines (normal C-style function pointers that point to closures). This is not doable in C++, which is the reason why C++ needs `std::function`. However there are low-level libraries (presumably partly written in assembly) such as [FFCALL](https://www.haible.de/bruno/packages-ffcall.html) that can do it for you (see man page for `callback`).

Comment: @Facundo basically if you're only ever going to get one context based callback from this library at a time then you create a static function that references a global variable that holds the object you want to call back into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [`libffcall`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/) to be the most appropriate solution for these kind of problems. Constructing closures on assembly/machine code is also a valid option, but with how easy and portable it is to implement the same thing using [`libffcall`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/), I don't think you'd want to mess with the former, unless you have some sort of (very restrictive) size constraint for your binaries.

[This is the final solution](https://github.com/fakuivan/SMConnect/blob/6dab4c68ff826879acc8d85fb7c3aea18920ec0e/natives.cpp#L38-L50).